# SVN - rename branch and switch

Tags: svn

I have a scenario and need some inputs. I have a typical svn setup of trunk/branches/tags. However for production machine we use a release branch. 
The issue is :
Production release branch has been messed up due to some unwanted checkins. We have created another branch from a stable revision but do not want to switch branches in production. Is it possible that I rename the existing release branch to something like : Release_Branch_notworking and then rename the New_ReleaseBranch to Release_Branch and do not switch branches on production machines. Has anyone tried this or any opinion if this will work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine.

Keep in mind there isn't a lot of "magic" around trunks or branches. They are simply folders with files (that happen to share a common revision history), and your production environment shouldn't really care what is inside the folder you happen to have named the "release" branch.

Also, if you really don't want those revisions, you do have the option of performing a "Revert to a previous revision" on the release branch to the last known good revision, and removing them completely (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503923/tortoise-svn-and-reverting-to-a-previous-revision) for a related response by Stefan, author of TortoiseSVN)

Comment: Ya i did a reverse merge.. removed those files but somehow things still not working.. i guess this is one of the reason why merging is so scary in svn