# How to get back to a revision in clean way

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a folder, with revision 1, 2, 3 for example. The current revision is 3. Now I want to go back to revision 1. And I suspect the revert is not quite right. 
So I just delete all files in the folder and then try to revert to revision 1. But I cannot find a way to do it. I either get 'conflict not set' or 'skipping missing target'. So how can I just pull a revision to a empty folder that already binded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Go back" isn't a clean term. Do you want just to see r1 in WC, or undo r2-r3?

Case 1: ["Update to revision"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5503985/960558) in context menu

Case 2: [Reverse Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513761/960558)

Comment: Thanks, I just want to have files of r1 in the work folder. leave r2 and r3 untouched in the repository.

Comment: @davidweng - case 1