# Remove specifics revisions from branch with tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need remove some revisions from my branch, because this revisions will be moved to another branch.

The revisions needed be remove are splited in show log, so I can't do a revert to 
the first revision without lose some important features which need still there.

How I can do it ?

Comment: I need to clarify. Do you have a revision that has both the changes you want reverted and changes you do not reverted?

Comment: Hi, Dialecticus. I edited the question.

Comment: The question is still not clear to me. You have for instance a Main branch. And you want some revisions from this Main branch to be "moved" to a new branch (you want those revision reverted from Main, and incorporated in New). Is this all, or is there something more? Is there a revision that should partially stay in Main and partially move in New?

Comment: I mean remove 5 revisions from my main branch wich need be removed. 
But between this 5 has another 21 revisions which can't be removed.

Comment: So, there is no "New" branch, and you just want to revert 5 particular revisions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverting to a previous revision using TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503923/reverting-to-a-previous-revision-using-tortoisesvn). You just have to use Ctrl+Click instead of Shift+Click, to select specific revisions, instead of a range.